# Unable to receive timer interrupt

Tags: timer, interrupt, stm32

I am using STM32L496RG board where I'm trying to generate a timer interrupt. But my code does not enter the `TIM3_IRQHandler` function at all. Initially, I thought my timer settings are wrong, so I created a test code using CUBEMX software to generate a timer interrupt, where it worked. I copied the settings from the test code to my code, but it still does not seem to work on my code. My timer initialisation -

```
/**
  * @brief TIM3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
void MX_TIM3_Init()
{
    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 0;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    while(1);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    while(1);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    while(1);
  }

}
```

I have started the timer using `HAL_TIM_BASE_START_IT(&htim3)`.I was also doubtful of my clock settings, so I have even copied the clock settings from my test program,but it still did not work. Clock settings -

```
void SystemClock_Config()
{
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 40;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    while(1);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    while(1);
  }

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    while(1);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}
```

Need some help to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Check that the interrupt is enabled both in the NVIC and in the timer peripheral

Comment: Thanks..I had to enable it in the NVIC which wasn't done.